# Android activity finish() not working

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish, startactivityforresult

I have a `Fragment` with `ImageView` inside. When I click on it, method `startActivityForResult` is called.

```
@OnClick(R.id.iv_avatar)
void setUpAvatar() {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(getContext(), CameraActivity.class), 0);
}
```

In CameraActivity I have menu item. When I click on it, I call `setResult` and `finish` methods. But they don't invoke. CameraActivity doesn't close, `onActivityResult` isn't called.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.me_done:
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            if (mData != null) {
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PICTURE, mData);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FROM_CAMERA, mFromCamera);
            }
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

I'am sure, that `onOptionsItemSelected` method is triggered and `setResult` and `finish` must to be called. What's wrong here?

Comment: Add some Log statements around your code. Debug the issue, see what you find

Comment: Add `break` at the end of each case

Comment: @VygintasB there is a return true

Comment: are your that `item.getItemId()` is `R.id.me_done`?

Comment: @cricket_007 well i had similar issue with switch and it didin't work properly till i added break;

Comment: @VygintasB Yes, your code was different. That isn't the issue here.

Comment: Have you tried ```getActivity().finish();```?

Comment: @PMateus I can't call getActivity() inside activity

Comment: @Blackbelt yes, my `item.getItemId()` is `R.id.me_done`. I've put breakpoint on switch statement and code below `case R.id.me_done` was called

Comment: oh wait, are you compiling against 25 and using android n on your test device?

Comment: @Blackbelt I've tested on two devices: nexus 5 on Android 6.0.1 and on Xiaomi with Android 5.0.1. The problem is that on nexus 5 all works fine, this issue is only for Xiaomi. In my gradle I have target and compile sdk version 24

Comment: maybe the payload is exceeding the maximum amount allowed. Are you sending back a bitmap in the bundle?

Comment: @Blackbelt I send byte array which represents an image from camera or gallery

Comment: then you are probably exceeding the maximum amount allowed for the binder transaction. Send back the image uri and let the destination activity load it

Comment: @Blackbelt oh, thanks a lot! I've changed logic and now I'am sending an uri of image. And it works!

Comment: nice, I am glad it worked